# Dropdown For the Registration Form not to be refreshed on submit and if error present (In case of validation)

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have a form named reg.php and its action is reg.php , i want the selected  dropdown value when clicked on submit to remain selected , what i have done so far is given below

```
<?php
if( $_POST['registerbtn']){
$selected_value = $_POST['selectID'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT  linecard_name FROM selection WHERE select_id = '$selected_value'");
$rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($query); 
$linecard_name= $rows['linecard_name'];
$sql = "SELECT select_id, linecard_name FROM selection " . "ORDER BY linecard_name";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);

while($rownw = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
if(  $rownw['linecard_name'] == $linecard_name)  {
$options = "<option  selected =selected  value=".$rownw['select_id']."> " .$rownw['linecard_name']. " </option> ";
}

}
}


require("./connect.php");
$sql = "SELECT select_id, linecard_name FROM selection ". "ORDER BY linecard_name";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);

while($rownw = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
 $options .= "<option value = ".$rownw['select_id']." > ".$rownw['linecard_name']. " </option> ";
} 
mysql_close() ;

$form = "<form action='./reg.php'  method='post'> 
<table>
<tr>
<td>  </td>
<td>  <font color='red'> $errormsg </font> </td> 
</tr>


<tr>
<td> Select  Linecard </td> 
<td> <Select name='selectID' >  <option value = '0'>  Select  from here </option> $options  </select></td> 

<tr> 
<td  > <input type='submit' name='registerbtn' value='Register' />   </td> 
</tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: check my answer.. is that what u want?

Answer (score 0):

If you make sure the form action is the same page as the form, you will be able access the POSTed data.

Answer (score 0):

After submitting form get posted value and compare with dropdown values ie

```
<?php
require("./connect.php");
$sql = "SELECT select_id, linecard_name FROM selection ". "ORDER BY linecard_name";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
$options = "<option value= '0' >  Select  from here </option>";
 $_POST['prefix']=isset($_POST['prefix']) ? $_POST['prefix'] : '';
    while($rownw = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
    $sel='';
        if($rownw['select_id']==$_POST['prefix']){
          $sel="selected='selected'";
        }
     $options .= "<option value = '".$rownw['select_id']."' ".$sel." > ".$rownw['linecard_name']. " </option> ";
    } 

mysql_close() ;

$form = "<form action='./reg.php'  method='post'> 
<table>
<tr>
<td>  </td>
<td>  <font color='red'> $errormsg </font> </td> 
</tr>

<tr>
<td>  Username  </td>
<td>  <input type='text' name='user' />  </td> 
</tr> 

<tr>
<td> Select  Linecard </td> 
<td> <Select name='selectID'> $options </select>
```

Try this

Comment: hey @sujal ... i want to get retain the dropdown value for the following code also can u help ?  <tr>   <td> <select name='prefix'> <option value='mr'> Mr </option> <option value='ms'> Ms </option> <option value='mrs'> Mrs </option> <option value='dr'> Dr </option> </select> </td>  </tr>

Comment: hey @sujal : Its not retaining the selected value on submit ??